# Problema con CMS

Tags: php, mysqli, cms

tengo en una web un pequeño CMS (basado en SCC Editor)  que permite crear listas ordenadas y desordenadas, negritas, cursivas y alguna cosa más. Como al escribir en la base de datos el texto de ese textarea donde funciona el CMS me incluía las etiquetas en formato [] [/], apliqué un strreplace así:

```
//Crear parrafos y reemplazar corchetes
$articulo = $_POST['articulo'];
$articulo = str_replace("[","<",$articulo);//cambiar abrir corchete por <
$articulo = str_replace("]",">",$articulo); //cambiar cerrar corchete por >
  $InsertQuery->bindColumn("articulo", "s", "".((isset($articulo))?$articulo:"")  ."", "WA_DEFAULT");
  $InsertGoTo = "comprobar_post.php";
if (function_exists("rel2abs")) $InsertGoTo = $InsertGoTo?rel2abs($InsertGoTo,dirname(__FILE__)):"";
$InsertQuery->redirect($InsertGoTo);
 }
```

Y funciona,  ya que en la bbdd escribe

```
 <b>texto</b>
```

para un texto en negrita.

El problema viene al recuperar ese texto para incluirlo en la publicación que me muestra

```
 <b>texto</b>
```

en lugar de **texto** como debería.

Aquí pongo el script del  del select:

```
<?php
$rsModificarPost = new WA_MySQLi_RS("rsModificarPost",$Prueba_MCC_i,1);
$rsModificarPost->setQuery("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post.p_id DESC");
$rsModificarPost->execute();
?>
```

Y aquí cómo recupero el texto ya en el body del documento php donde se publica con su nl2br para generar apariencias de altos de línea:

```
<div style="color:#000000; font-weight:400; border-bottom:1px #CCC dotted; padding-bottom:20px;">
 <?php echo  nl2br($rsModificarPost->getColumnVal("articulo")); ?>

</div>
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme, por favor? Muchas gracias

Comment: Si haces el echo '<b>texto</b>' si te funciona?, si es así capaz y tienes que hacer una conversión a string de lo que llega en la consulta.

Comment: Gracias, zerocool.
En efecto hacer un echo con '<b>texto</b>' sí devuelve **texto** escrito en negritas. 
¿Cómo puedo convertir mi consulta a string? 
Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: He probado a recuperar el texto de mi consulta utilizando Heredoc así:
    <?php
    $articulo = nl2br($rsModificarPost->getColumnVal("articulo")); 
    echo <<<EOT
    "$articulo" 
     EOT;
     ?>
Pero sucede lo mismo: entra el texto con las etiquetas y sin el formato deseado.

Comment: Ok, desde el inspector ves la etiqueta? te sale como parte del html? podrías dejar en un fiddle o algo así la prueba?. saludos.

Comment: Ah, muchas gracias, zerocool. 
He hecho algo: en la ventana del navegador donde veo el contenido en local de la página: Di "Ver código fuente" y, resulta, que tengo todos los '<> </>' de las etiquetas convertidos a htmlentities... (¿¿¿!!!). La verdad es que no entiendo cómo ha pasado esto pero se me ocurre una solución para evitar que se muestre mal:
Voy a probar a utilizar un str_replace para convertirlas de nuevo a los valores que permitan visualizar ok el código. Ya os diré.
Gracias y saludos

Comment: Hola no había tenido tiempo libre, si es éso no tienes que hacerlo. usa html_entity_decode saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias, zerocool. 
Al final lo he resuelto simplificando las cosas e invirtiendo el orden: en mi idea inicial estaba el reemplazar los corchetes que me proporciona mi entrada de datos (para un elemento '**texto**' SCC Editor me escribe '[b]texto[/b]') para que en la base de datos se escribiese ya el html.

Así que eliminé ese filtro en la entrada de datos y lo he puesto en la salida cuando hago el echo que imprime el contenido de la columna artículo.

He creado una variable '$articulo'. Este es mi script:

```
div class="articulo">
        <?php 
        $articulo = nl2br($rsListado->getColumnVal("articulo"));
        $articulo = str_replace("[","<",$articulo);//cambiar abrir corchete por <
        $articulo = str_replace("]",">",$articulo); //cambiar cerrar corchete por >
        $articulo = str_replace("&#x2F;","/",$articulo); //cambiar htmlentitie cerrar por/ >
 echo ($articulo); 
        ?> 

</div>
```

Gracias por vuestra atención y un saludo. :)